# How to deal with Error 0 in CakePHP Unit Testing?

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp-2.0, sha1

Whilst trying to access my unit tests through the browser I encountered an error '0'. (See full error below). My cake application is inside a docker container, with another docker container running alongside it to run the database.

I checked the test.php file and the phpunit.phar and phpunit.php files, but cannot uncover any cause for the error. I've also tried to set up a test database, and I'm not sure if that might be causing the error.

```
0
phar "/var/www/<app_name>/app/Vendor/phpunit.phar" SHA1 signature could not be verified: broken signature
```

I should be able to see a list of all the core tests that I have available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying replacing your phpunit.phar file with an updated version. It might be corrupted.

➜ wget -O phpunit https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit-8.phar

➜ chmod +x phpunit

➜ ./phpunit --version